# JavaScript inherit object values

Tags: javascript, object, superclass, inheritance

is it possible to inherit an Object (reference) value from a class?

```
function A()
{
    this.x = {};
}

function B()
{
    this.y = {};
}
B.prototype = new A();
//...
var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();
alert(b1.x == b2.x);    // true
alert(b1.y == b2.y);    // false
```

but I want both to be false...  B.x should be different for each instance of B.

Comment: But there's only one A; if you want different As, having a single A as a prototype won't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Call A's constructor from B:

```
function B() {
  A.apply(this);
  this.y = {};
}
B.prototype = new A()
```

Imagine it as if it were a call to super in Java. That is in fact how it works in Closure Library and some other JavaScript frameworks.

```
var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();
alert(b1.x === b2.x); //false
```

Comment: That's because you forgot to add the y in your jsfiddle. It returns false for b1.x === b2.x which is what he asked for.

Comment: In your original post, there was no y; +1 for a simpler solution.

Comment: Because that wasn't the question. In your jsfiddle it returns true once because it's comparing two undefined!

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** Bjorn Tipling's solution is the proper way to do this.

---

Try recreating the prototype when a new `B` is created:

```
function A()
{
    this.x = {};
}

function B()
{
    //c is recreated each time with a new
    //prototype to screw with.
    var c = function() {
        this.y = {};
    };
    //instead of assigning 1 single instance of "A" to
    //B's prototype. We a assign a new "A" instance each time
    //a B is created. Therefore each instance of B has its
    //own A instance in its prototype.
    c.prototype = new A();

    return new c;
}
//...
var b1 = new B();
var b2 = new B();
alert(b1.x == b2.x);    // false
alert(b1.y == b2.y);    // false
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vHtcs/3/)

Comment: I didn't know you could return from a function you're calling with new. Man JavaScript bugs me sometimes.

Comment: sorry, has been a dumb idea - no deletion of comments :-)